# In what years has Picard been depicted in-universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, star-trek-picard

With the release of *Star Trek: Picard*, we've now seen Jean-Luc Picard in at least two new periods.

**In which years has he been depicted so far?**

*Depicted* means that action occurs at a particular time or an in-universe depiction (hologram, photograph, video) is shown on screen.  Main TV/film canon.

Hallucinations and the like don't count ("The Inner Light", "The Battle"), but time travel does.  I'm going to assume that when Q takes Picard to another time period, this really is time travel even though it's probably debatable.

In cases where the exact year is not known, a best guess or a range is acceptable.

Comment: He was a little kiddie in Rascals. He was a teen (in photo) in Nemesis, a grown man in TNG, an older grown man in STP and an elderly man in All Good things

Comment: @Valorum, I know you're kidding, but just to be clear, I'm asking about the year where he is depicted, not his apparent age.

Comment: Yay, it's this again.

Answer (score 2):

Picard has been depicted on screen during the following time periods. This is a Community Wiki answer so that anyone can update it during ST:Picard, or for any times that may have been missed.

- 3.5 billion years in the past (All Good Things)
- 1893 (Time's Arrow part II)
- 2063 (ST:First Contact)
- 2327 (TNG:*Tapestry* flashback)
- 2364 through 2370 (TNG show timeline)
- 2371 (ST:Generations)
- 2373 (ST:First Contact)
- 2375 (ST:Insurrection)
- 2379 (ST:Nemesis)
- 2385 (Picard:*The End is the Beginning* flashback)
- 2395 (All Good Things)
- 2399 through ???? (Picard show timeline)

Comment: You missed c. 2385, flashback in STP 103, "The End is the Beginning"

Comment: Also, the depictions in the Academy, "Tapestry" and *Nemesis*

Comment: @ThePopMachine I don't have CBS All Access, so it's unlikely I'll see the new show any time soon. I've added in the Tapestry flashbacks. Feel free to edit in any other's you notice I might have missed.

Comment: Xantec, I feel sorry for you...

Comment: @Xantec  According to Star Trek Transcripts, when the Enterprise travels back in time pursuing the Borg, Data manages to find the exact date:  "DATA: April fourth, two thousand sixty-three."  So the date of that part of First Contact should be April fourth 2063, not 2060.

Comment: So, my question is whether we know whether the picture of Picard at the Academy in Nemesis is the same year as Tapestry or not.

Comment: Also, is there ever any picture which purports to be from the Stargazer?

Comment: @M.A.Golding Apologies, I was going by the dates listed on Memory Alpha. Thanks for the update.